# How to skip (do not process at all) some XSLT elements based on specific rule?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<element>
 <A>192.168.188.100</A>
 <B>/shelf=1</B>
</element>
<element>
 <A>192.168.188.100</A>
 <B>/slot=1</B>
</element>
<element>
 <A>192.168.188.23</A>
 <B>/port=client:1:3:1-2</B>
</element>
</data>
```

I have XSLT mapping which works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <max:SyncCIDW>
    <max:CIDWSet>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/element" />
    </max:CIDWSet>
    </max:SyncCIDW>
</xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="element"> 
    <max:CI>
        <max:CINUM><xsl:value-of select="A"/></max:CINUM>
    </max:CI>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I skip element, not to be added to my mapping at all but only if  element starts with "/port="?
So in this example only third element should be processed through the XSLT?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data/element[starts-with(B,'/port')]" />
```

Selects only those elements whose `B` child node's text starts with `/port`.

There's a bug in your `element` template however:

```
<max:CINUM><xsl:value-of select="ip"/></max:CINUM>
                                 ^^
```

There's no child node named `ip`, maybe you meant to use `A` instead?

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <max:SyncCIDW>
            <max:CIDWSet>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="data/element[starts-with(B,'/port')]" />
            </max:CIDWSet>
        </max:SyncCIDW>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="element"> 
        <max:CI>
            <max:CINUM><xsl:value-of select="A"/></max:CINUM>
        </max:CI>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:SyncCIDW xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <max:CIDWSet>
      <max:CI>
         <max:CINUM>192.168.188.23</max:CINUM>
      </max:CI>
   </max:CIDWSet>
</max:SyncCIDW>
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, and sorry one more question if  I want to retreive value and from B and to put it in some other element but without this part "/port=" how can I do it?  for example to have also <max:B><xsl:value-of select="B"/></max:B>  but without prefix "/port="

Comment: Look up the `substring()` function in any XSLT reference

Comment: Hi I looked but is sub-strings static value as first parameter? While value in B element is different always? I marked your feedback as answer

Comment: No, `substring(B,7)` will return the contents of `B`'s text starting at position 7, i.e. after `/port=`